# Results from database I created do not appear in wordpress.

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

Example of code where I can make a table's properties show on page.

```
if (current_user_can('administrator'))
    {
      global $wpdb;
      $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "   SELECT * 
                                      FROM  $wpdb->posts
                                      WHERE post_type = 'product'
                                     " );

   foreach ( $result as $row )
    {

   echo $row->ID.'<br/>';
   echo $row->post_title.'<br/>';
}
```

Then I put data into the table and I get nothing, not ever error messages.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens ? And how can I make any table's results appear in my page? 
Thank you

Comment: try a var_dump of `$result` to see the contents if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if it helps

1. Enable debug in wp-config using define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
2. Print sql query using $wpdb->show_errors(); and add query you get directly in phpmyadmin and check if it works.
3. Also add $wpdb->prefix_{table_name_here}, before table name.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$query1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\WP\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 618: I did all of these,this is what I got when I saved my query as "query1"

Comment: Try to use $wpdb->show_errors(); to show query and sql errors and try to run query you are trying to do in phpmyadmin first

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_product_list(){
$output = '';
if (current_user_can('administrator'))
    {
      global $wpdb;
      $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "   SELECT * FROM  $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product'" );
    foreach ( $result as $row )
    {
       $output .= $row->ID.'<br/>';
       $output .= $row->post_title.'<br/>';
    }
}
return $output;}add_shortcode( 'product_list', 'get_product_list' );
```

use [product_list] shortcode anywhere you want to display products list.